# Java: String padding failed

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I want to align the number on the string like that:

```
3 x  89 kg
3 x 133 kg
```

I use this format:

```
String.format("%1$3d x %2$3d kg", nb, weight);
```

But the result is not correct:

[image]

Comment: It seems you are using a proportional font. That means that spaces are narrower than digits. You should use a fixed-width font if you want them to align in this method, e.g. Courier.

Comment: Unrelated: Since you're just using the values in order, there's no need to specify indexes, so `"%3d x %3d kg"` would work too.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to the font(because the characters don't have the same width) Change the font to a **monospaced** font and the problem will be solved(I recommend **Consolas** font for this)